# Create immutable object in javascript

Tags: javascript, immutability

I have a routine where I receive some data from an api. I'd like to store this data in an object, but after that i want to "lock" this object and not allow any change to the properties or their values after that point. Is that possible? (If possible using only ES5).

Comment: you mean like [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: @palaѕн OP wants to keep it ES5 only

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you wish for an object to not be able to be modified you can use [`Object.freeze`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze).

> The `Object.freeze()` method freezes an object: that is, prevents new
>   properties from being added to it; prevents existing properties from
>   being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their
>   enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed, it
>   also prevents the prototype from being changed.  The method returns
>   the object in a frozen state.

If you simply want to prevent a variable from being reassigned you can use `const` (ES6), however note that:

> The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It
>   does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable
>   identifier cannot be reassigned.

E.g, the following is perfectly valid

```js
const a = { x: 7 }
a.x = 9
console.log(a.x) // 9
```

However, trying to reassign a variable declared with `const` will throw a `TypeError`:

```js
const a = 5
a = 7
```

Comment: This won't prevent you from re-assigning a different value to a `var`.

Comment: technically the const variable is not mutable. It's const. The object the variable is referencing is mutable but the variable is not and can not be changed to reference a different object.

Comment: Object.freeze was kinda good enough, but i fell into a different problem: Before freezing my object i assign those values to a different var and then freeze the original var. When i tried to remove itens from the second var(not freezed) it raised this error (angular.js:13294 TypeError: Cannot add/remove sealed array elements
    at Array.splice (<anonymous>))

Comment: Thats probably due to those vars referencing the same memory space. Any idea on that second issue (Guess i should open a new question)

Comment: To my knowledge, Object.freeze enforces immutability only up to 1 level.

Comment: @ArunkumarSrisailapathi, correct. You’d have to do this for the nested objects as well

Comment: @ViníciusMussato you should not assign the second var to the original var. it does not make a copy of the original object, it only copies the reference of the first object. if you want a copy of the original object use
```const a={ c:1, d:2 };
const b=Object.assign({},a);
Object.freeze(a);
delete b.d;
```

Answer (score 6):

For Immutable object we can use below approches

1. `Object.freeze()`
2. To enforce object immutability while update the object make sure to
3. use `Object.assign({},a,{foo:'bar'})` rather than `a.foo='bar'`
4. we can use `spread(...)` operator.

**See example:**

```
var person={name:'pavan',age:26}

var newPerson={...person,name:'raju'}

console.log(newPerson ===person) //false
console.log(person)  //{name:'pavan',age:26}
console.log(newPerson)  //{name:'raju',age:26}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There's no good way to enforce `const`-ness is ES5.

Comment: Not sure why you'd think `Object.freeze` from ES5 is not a good solution to the OP's question. The OP said they wanted the _object_ locked down and said nothing about reassigning a _variable_, which is all that `const` does. I reread the OP's question several times and think freezing it is exactly what they have in mind. Cheers.

Comment: @RayToal If you look at the edit history of the question, you'll see that the version that I answered asked: "Id'like to store this data in a var, but after that i want to "lock" this var". A subsequent edit changed the meaning of the OP's question and invalidated the answer.

Comment: Oh dear thank you I did not see that the question was edited. Locking a _var_ is certainly different that making the _object_ immutable

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) method which freezes an object. A frozen object can no longer be changed and prevents :

- New properties from being added to it
- Existing properties from being removed
- Changing the enumerability, configurability, or writability of existing properties
- The values of existing properties from being changed.

Demo **:**

```js
const obj = {
  name: 'Alpha',
  age: 30,
  hobbies: ['reading', 'writing']
};

Object.freeze(obj);

obj.name = 'Beta';
obj.hobbies[0] = 'painting'; 

console.log(obj.name); // Alpha (It works fine with the properties which contains primitive values)
console.log(obj.hobbies[0]); // painting (It does not work for nested objects/array)
```

If you see in above code snippet, It works fine with the properties which contains primitive values but it is updating the values of nested `object/array`.

Hence, You can try `as const` If you are working with typescript in your requirement. It will freeze the whole object along with the nested properties with object/array.

Answer (score 0):

If you separate you code into pure and impure parts (as with functional core, imperative shell), you can get by in the pure parts using objects and arrays and not, as a matter of discipline, mutating them.

I've done this for years and have [a library](https://github.com/mlanza/atomic) which aids this style of development.  I can't imagine needing the insurance policy of having to `Object.freeze` everything.  Now, eventually, when [records and tuples](https://tc39.es/proposal-record-tuple/) is adopted into the spec you can just use them instead!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.freeze()` + `get` method ([accessor properties](https://javascript.info/property-accessors))

```js
const obj = {
  label: 'Jim',
  leisures: ['gaming', 'work out'],
  get toys(){
    return ['ball', 'car']
  },
};

Object.freeze(obj);

obj.label = 'Dwight'; // immutable
obj.leisures[0] = 'coding';  // mutable
obj.toys[0] = 'axe';  // immutable

console.log(obj.label); // Jim 
console.log(obj.leisures[0]); // coding 
console.log(obj.toys[0]); // ball, because the `get` method makes toys() accesible, but isnt mutable.
```